# How to load a saved Sortable in Angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable tabset and everything work as expected, but I want when user refresh page, find his tab order is saved and isn't lost.

```
 <uib-tabset  ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="tab-container"  my-restrict access="staff-businessDeveloper">
                    <uib-tab ng-controller="FirstCtrl" >
                        <tab-heading>
                            <i class="icon icon-user-following "></i> Dealers
                        </tab-heading>
                        <div class="panel-body table-responsive no-padding">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                            Some Stuff
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab ng-controller="SecondTabCtrl" >
                        <tab-heading>
                            <i class="icon icon-user-following "></i> Dealers2
                        </tab-heading>
                        <div class="panel-body table-responsive no-padding">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                            Some Stuff
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </uib-tab>
                </uib-tabset>
```

and here the logic of the sortable in the controller

```
      $scope.sortableOptions = {
    axis: 'x',
    containment : "parent",
    cursor : "move",
    tolerance : "pointer",
    start: function(e, ui) {
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
      $localStorage.tabOrder[$localStorage.me.id] = angular.element(this).sortable('toArray');
    }
  };
```

You can see that I save tab Order in $localStorage, How can I load it ?

Comment: So if the second tab is dragged to first position, next time when it loads as the first tab should it get `SecondTabCtrl`..? But ot is the first tab right..? Don't you think you should have a generic controller..?

Comment: and your data like `Dealers2` should be stored somewhere like in scope, not hard coded in HTML,  so that it can be modified without manipulating DOM. When you fix all this, then loading initial data from local storage, a rest api or whatever will become easy

Comment: @TJ, so that is the only the way ? because these tabs are everywhere in company project and contains a lot of dynamic data,

Comment: I don't see dynamic data bindings in your example..? see [mcve] and you didn't answer my first question...

Comment: @TJ Sorry, I was working on dynamically displaying templates in ng-repeat directive, and it currently working, so I guess the question was answered.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using this [library](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) - angular storage. It provides very convenient functions for accessing local storage. It will also fall back to using cookies should local or session storage not be available.

For example - if I want to store something called "settings" I'd do this:

```
store.set('settings', {settings stuff});
```

This can then be retrieved by doing this:

```
var settings = store.get('settings');
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I don't have problem with $localStorage. my problem is I don't know how to load saved order of the tabs, let's say I use angular storage, where do I put  "settings" and what do I write to make sortable load order that is saved in "settings".

Comment: @user1493376 could you post a jsfiddle of what you've done so I can tinker with it?

Comment: same as http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/KtsFH , the difference I'm using uib-tab instead of li and that it.